# Catching who wrote the code by using TFS automatically?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Lets assume I have an object that keep an filename and one of its row number in the project. I want to make a search by using this object to find who  wrote that part of code and of course when by looking at TFS automatically. In a nutshell I am trying to write a method to do all these operations.

I wonder where TFS keeps all these information ? So I can make comparison

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to create a different version of TFS's "Annotate" feature (aka GIT's "Blame")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I wonder where TFS keeps all this [information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/13b56618-3b0b-4e3d-b20f-8337c6869e09/)*"

File information is stored in dbo.dimfile found in TFS_Warehouse. From there, you can examine what is available in terms of data and build a query to hopefully meet your needs.

TFS 2010 has three primary databases for data storage:

> **TFS_Config** : It’s the root database
>   and it contains centralized TFS
>   configuration data, including the list
>   of all team projects exist in TFS
>   server.
>
> **TFS_Warehouse** : The data warehouse
>   contains all the reporting data of
>   served by this server (farm).
>
> **TFS_*** : This contains individual team
>   project collection data. This database
>   contains all the operational data of
>   team project collection regardless of
>   subsystem. In additional to this, you
>   will have databases for SharePoint and
>   Report Server.